# 2013 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

Seasoned Advice's [third moderator election](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Jefromi]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with him as he learns the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/916021/0).

Comment: Grats Jefromi__

Comment: Congratulations.  You must use this power only for good :-)